# Divisor of zero in Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Working with a nontrivial ring with unity, if $a\neq\pm1$ and $a^2=1$, then $a+1$ and $a-1$ are divisors of zero.

I'm not sure I understand how $a\neq\pm1$ but $a^2=1$? I know divisors of zero are nonzero elements or additive identities. Does this mean 1 is an additive identity?

EDIT: I understand now about 1 being the multiplicative identity. Could I take: $a^2=1 \rightarrow a^2-1=0 \rightarrow (a+1)(a-1)=0$ thus $a-1$ and $a+1$ are divsors of zero by definition?

Comment: $1$ is the multiplicative identity in the ring.

Answer (score 2):

How about $R=\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, the ring of integers modulo $8$. In this ring $3^2=1$ (this means $3^2\equiv1\pmod 8$).

Comment: In this case you are letting $a=3$ then $a-1\rightarrow 3-1=2$ and $a+1\rightarrow 3+1=4$ are the divisors of zero? Is this because $2+2+2+2=4+4=0$ in this ring?

Comment: @KellyR I would say $2\times 4=0$ in $R$ myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=M_2(K)$ be the ring of $2\times 2$-matrices over $K$, and $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$. Then $A\neq \pm I$, but $A^2=I$. Here $I=\operatorname{diag}(1,1)$ is the unity of $R$.

Comment: I apologize I'm not entirely following. In this example 1 is the unit or multiplicative inverse but aren't we looking for the additive inverse?

Comment: I just wanted to answer your question "I'm not sure I understand how $a\neq\pm1$ but $a^2=1$?", where $1$ is the unity.